# Precargar fichero en input type='file'

Tags: html5, formularios, entrada

¿Hay algún modo de que un input file de html contenga un fichero precargado al desplegarse el formulario?
Lo que pretendo es que en un formulario de configuración, se precarguen los campos guardados por el usuario (almacenados en la base de datos) cuando vuelve a acceder al formulario.

Gracias!

Plantilla twig

```
{% for input in inputs %}
    <label>  
    {% set string = input.tag %}
    {% set string = string|replace({'_': ' '}) %}
    {{string}}
    </label><br>
    {% if input.codigo == 'number' %}
        <input type="number" name={{input.tag}} value={{input.tag}} id="{{input.tag}}">
    {% elseif input.codigo == 'text_strong' or input.codigo == 'text_simple' or input.codigo == 'link' %}
        <input type="text" name={{input.tag}} value={{input.tag}} id="{{input.tag}}" >
    {% elseif input.codigo == 'imagen' %}
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name={{input.tag}} value={{input.tag}} id="{{input.tag}}">
    {% elseif input.codigo == 'text_long' %}
        <textarea maxlength="400" name={{input.tag}} id="{{input.tag}}"style="resize: vertical;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </textarea>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Una vez recogidos los datos por ajax recorro el array

```
$.each($values,function(index, el) {
        // Compruebo tipo de input (1,2,3,5,7 = texto) 4=file 6=link
        if(el.tipo_field_id == 1 || el.tipo_field_id == 2 || el.tipo_field_id == 3 || el.tipo_field_id == 5 || el.tipo_field_id == 7){ 
            $('#'+el.tag).val(el.texto);
        }else if(el.tipo_field_id == 4){
            //Cargar el fichero;
        }else if(el.tipo_field_id == 6){
            $('#'+el.tag).prop("href" , el.texto);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

por temas de seguridad no creo que los navegadores te lo permitan, pero lo que puedes hacer es tener un `input type="hidden"` que tenga como value la url de tu fichero en el servidor y antes de mandar el formulario si el value del `input type="file"` está vacío coges los datos de la url del hidden

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar referencias para enriquecer tu respuesta? Gracias.

Comment: sin una pregunta más concisa no hay nada que pueda hacer, necesito un ejemplo de código de lo que pretendes hacer

Comment: No soy el autor original, sólo quería aconsejarte que para mejorar la calidad de tu respuesta, podrías incluir referencias a los motivos que expones y elimines frases indecisas como ".. no creo que los navegadores..". Si tu respuesta alcanza una calidad aceptable yo te recompensaría con un positivo (e imagino que otros compañeros harían igual).